# How do I give an own ip address to docker for Windows container?

Tags: docker

I want to export the complete ip connectivity (UDP and TCP) from a docker container with a Linux app  (ie give it's own ip address (in the same subnet as the host), that can be accessed from the host and from other physical machines on the network).

What do I need to configure in Windows, what in docker, what inside the container?

(NB: I don NOT want to expose ports as part of the host).

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem (for me) by installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box and using the docker containers from there. Not the most elegant solution but working on first try.